# Could not resolve a persistence unit error - Netbeans 7.3/7.4 and Glassfish 4

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, netbeans-7.4

I've been adapting a code sample from the JSF2.0 Complete Reference textbook (the Virtual Trainer application) to run using CDI. All was going well until I started adding some of the JSF code at which point the deployment began to repeatedly fail stating that it could not resolve a persistence unit. I was somewhat puzzled as I hadn't touched any of my entity code or controller beans but rolled the application back anyway (manually - I didn't have it attached to Subversion a the time). Despite this, the error persists so something has changed but I can't find it! Others have reported an identical error that was associated with a misplaced persistence.xml file but my copy seems to be deployed correctly as far as I can tell.

The project is based on a Maven Java EE Web Archetype and I'm using Netbeans 7.4 (final), Java EE7 and Glassfish 4. It's also worth noting that as I started to write some JSF pages, Netbeans seemed to develop hiccups as it didn't recognise some of the tags (e.g. ) so I suspect there is a bug there.

I'd be really grateful if anyone has any ideas!

Stacktrace as follows:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerBean/em] in the scope of the module called [trainer]. Please verify your application.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUViaEMRef(BundleDescriptor.java:727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUsViaPCRefs(BundleDescriptor.java:715)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.findReferencedPUs(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:996)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
SEVERE:   Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerBean/em] in the scope of the module called [trainer]. Please verify your application.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUViaEMRef(BundleDescriptor.java:727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUsViaPCRefs(BundleDescriptor.java:715)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.findReferencedPUs(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:996)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Persistence.xml (exploded file location: trainer/target/classes/META-INF/)
File was not changed at the time the error occurred but I recreated the file to be sure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Trainer_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Problem solved! There appeared to be a conflict associated with a Maven repository I had to add in order to use javax.validation.constraintpayload in a EmailConstraint interface...

Answer (score 0):

Further detail on the issue.
The code example I'm using creates a couple of constraint validators - one checks that usernames are unique, the other that email formats are correct. The interfaces required utilise the ConstraintPayload class and as I was using a Maven archetype I duly searched for the required dependency and repository entries ([Maven Hub](http://mavenhub.com/c/javax/validation/constraintpayload)). There were two to choose from - I selected the first as it mentioned Glassfish specifically - this caused an immediate crash on deployment with the Persistence Unit error described in my original question. Fortunately the second entry appears to work (although I haven't actually tested the validator classes as of yet!) It would appear that there was some conflict but I am unclear as to the exact details.

For reference, examples of constraint validator code:

```
package com.jsfcompref.trainer.entity;


import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintPayload;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UseridUniquenessConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UseridUniquenessConstraint {

    String message() default "A user with that userid already exists";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends ConstraintPayload>[] payload() default {};   

----

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class UseridUniquenessConstraintValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<UseridUniquenessConstraint, String> {

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {


        UserRegistry registry = UserRegistry.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean result = true;

        if (null != registry) {
            result = (null != registry.getUserByUserid(value));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void initialize(UseridUniquenessConstraint arg0) {
    }

}
```

Maven pom entries that caused the issue:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-b69</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
        <id>glassfish</id>
        <name>Glassfish</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/glassfish</url>
</repository>
```

Amended Maven pom entries that lead to successful deployment (I didn't go for these originally as they relate to Hibernate and I'm using the default JPA2.1 Eclipselink provided...however, they are JSR(303) so may well actually be more recent and thus compatible with Glassfish 4)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-JBoss-4.0.0.Beta3A</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Java.net</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/java.net2</url>
</repository>
```